# url conflict in Django

Tags: django, url

I get the same page regardless of what url I use. I get the home.html page for all the ones I have listed. Any suggestions would be valuable. Thanks!

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^signup/', include('log.urls')),
    url(r'^login/', include('log.urls')),
    url(r'^logout/', include('log.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('log.urls')),
]
```

and from

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

# We are adding a URL called /home
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.logout, name = 'logout'),
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is wrong, for everything you are including `log.urls`. It should be

**project urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('log.urls')),
]
```

and then,

**log urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name = 'logout'),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```